# how to find percentage of total in groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  Date        tank     hose     quantity     count      set     flow
  01-01-2018  1        1        20           100        211     12.32
  01-01-2018  1        2        20           200        111     22.32
  01-01-2018  1        3        20           200        123     42.32
  02-01-2018  1        1        10           100        211     12.32
  02-01-2018  1        2        10           200        111     22.32
  02-01-2018  1        3        10           200        123     42.32
```

I want to calculate percentage of `quantity` and `count` grouping by `Date` and `tank`. My desired dataframe

```
  Date        tank   hose   quantity   count   set   flow    perc_quant  perc_count
  01-01-2018  1        1    20         100     211   12.32   33.33       20
  01-01-2018  1        2    20         200     111   22.32   33.33       40
  01-01-2018  1        3    20         200     123   42.32   33.33       40
  02-01-2018  1        1    10         100     211   12.32   25          20
  02-01-2018  1        2    20         200     111   22.32   50          40
  02-01-2018  1        3    10         200     123   42.32   25          40
```

I am doing following to achieve this

```
   test = df.groupby(['Date','tank']).apply(lambda x:
                                             100 * x / float(x.sum()))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function, [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
f = lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum())
df = df.join(df.groupby(['Date','tank'])['quantity','count'].transform(f).add_prefix('perc_'))
```

Or specify new columns names:

```
df[['perc_quantity','perc_count']] = (df.groupby(['Date','tank'])['quantity','count']
                                        .transform(f))
```

---

```
print (df)
         Date  tank  hose  quantity  count  set   flow  perc_quantity  \
0  01-01-2018     1     1        20    100  211  12.32      33.333333   
1  01-01-2018     1     2        20    200  111  22.32      33.333333   
2  01-01-2018     1     3        20    200  123  42.32      33.333333   
3  02-01-2018     1     1        10    100  211  12.32      33.333333   
4  02-01-2018     1     2        10    200  111  22.32      33.333333   
5  02-01-2018     1     3        10    200  123  42.32      33.333333   

   perc_count  
0        20.0  
1        40.0  
2        40.0  
3        20.0  
4        40.0  
5        40.0
```