# Percent of total with repeated products

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregation-framework

My data is in this format and at the moment I do not wish to change the source data file. I am having trouble using `transform, apply` to calculate the percentage of the total. Referencing from both of these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940487/how-to-find-percentage-of-total-in-groupby-in-pandas) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby), I came to realize the first link may not work as intended for my problem.

```
df_list = [['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'QUARTER', '2020-06-01', 100], ['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'YEARLY', '2020-06-01', 1000],
           ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'QUARTER', '2020-06-01', 200],  ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'YEARLY', '2020-06-01', 5000], 
           ['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'QUARTER', '2020-03-01', 300],  ['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'YEARLY', '2020-03-01', 2000],
           ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'QUARTER', '2020-03-01', 700],  ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'YEARLY', '2020-03-01', 8000], 
           ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'QUARTER', '2020-06-01', 100], ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'YEARLY', '2020-06-01', 1000],
           ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'QUARTER', '2020-06-01', 200],  ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'YEARLY', '2020-06-01', 5000], 
           ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'QUARTER', '2020-06-01', 200],    ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'YEARLY', '2020-06-01', 5000],
           ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'QUARTER', '2020-03-01', 300],  ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'YEARLY', '2020-03-01', 2000],
           ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'QUARTER', '2020-03-01', 700],  ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'YEARLY', '2020-03-01', 8000],
           ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'QUARTER', '2020-03-01', 200],  ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'YEARLY', '2020-03-01', 5000]]

column_names = ['MARKET', 'PRODUCT', 'TIMEPERIOD', 'DATE', 'VALUES']
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = column_names)

def market_share(x):
    try:
        ms = x / float(x.sum())
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        ms = 0
    
    return ms
    

df['MS'] = (df.groupby(['MARKET', 'TIMEPERIOD', 'DATE'])['VALUES']
                                        .transform(market_share))
```

Output from above is:

```
    MARKET     PRODUCT       TIMEPERIOD    DATE         VALUES   MS
0   USA MARKET  APPLE        QUARTER       2020-06-01   100     0.333333
1   USA MARKET  APPLE        YEARLY        2020-06-01   1000    0.166667
2   USA MARKET  PEAR         QUARTER       2020-06-01   200     0.666667
3   USA MARKET  PEAR         YEARLY        2020-06-01   5000    0.833333
4   USA MARKET  APPLE        QUARTER       2020-03-01   300     0.300000
5   USA MARKET  APPLE        YEARLY        2020-03-01   2000    0.200000
6   USA MARKET  PEAR         QUARTER       2020-03-01   700     0.700000
7   USA MARKET  PEAR         YEARLY        2020-03-01   8000    0.800000
8   UK MARKET   WATERMELON   QUARTER       2020-06-01   100     0.200000
9   UK MARKET   WATERMELON   YEARLY        2020-06-01   1000    0.090909
10  UK MARKET   WATERMELON   QUARTER       2020-06-01   200     0.400000
11  UK MARKET   WATERMELON   YEARLY        2020-06-01   5000    0.454545
12  UK MARKET   GRAPE        QUARTER       2020-06-01   200     0.400000
13  UK MARKET   GRAPE        YEARLY        2020-06-01   5000    0.454545
14  UK MARKET   WATERMELON   QUARTER       2020-03-01   300     0.250000
15  UK MARKET   WATERMELON   YEARLY        2020-03-01   2000    0.133333
16  UK MARKET   WATERMELON   QUARTER       2020-03-01   700     0.583333
17  UK MARKET   WATERMELON   YEARLY        2020-03-01   8000    0.533333
18  UK MARKET   GRAPE        QUARTER       2020-03-01   200     0.166667
19  UK MARKET   GRAPE        YEARLY        2020-03-01   5000    0.333333
```

Now, this is not wrong per se, for if you want to calculate the percentage of total for Watermelon in the UK Market in 2020-06-01 Quarter, you can just use 0.2+0.4=0.6, but I wish that I can have the Market Share (Percentage of Total) to be 0.6 directly, instead of just 0.2 and 0.4 respectively for me to add up.

```
UK MARKET   WATERMELON   QUARTER       2020-06-01   300  0.6
```

This problem can be resolved using the second link I posted, but I would want to know what I did wrong here to not get the aggregation correctly.

Comment: have you debugged this?

Comment: No, I can’t debug this using the code I pasted. However it can be done using the way in the second link. But I am more inclined to know how to resolve it using the method I shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The data looks right to me.

You are grouping by on 3 indices: `['MARKET', 'TIMEPERIOD', 'DATE']`.

Remember that you are not grouping by on `PRODUCT`

```
UK MARKET   WATERMELON   QUARTER       2020-06-01   300  0.6
```

The corresponding grouped enteries should be:

```
8   UK MARKET   WATERMELON   QUARTER       2020-06-01   100     0.200000
10  UK MARKET   WATERMELON   QUARTER       2020-06-01   200     0.400000
12  UK MARKET   GRAPE        QUARTER       2020-06-01   200     0.400000
```

So the values look right to me.

Comment: Yes the values are indeed right. But the thing is that watermelon appeared twice in UK market. I want them to appear as one in the end result as just 0.6 of the market share. The result I’m showing separately shows the market share of the watermelon - when I want them to be shown as one entity.

Comment: For aggregated result for Watermelon, you can also groupby on `PRODUCT` too. What am I missing?

Comment: If you do that, you will ignore the GRAPE in the UK Market, and now Watermelon will have 0.33 and 0.66 respectively, which is wrong